# Settlers-like terrain representation

Tags: data-structure

Remember this beauty? I'm playing it now on my old Amiga 1200.

[image]

My question is: How do you think they represented the terrain, data structure wise? Obviously it's some kind of points, with a height. Or hexagons. And how did they decide which dots were buildable?

**EDIT:** I could rephrase the question to say "how do I achieve this kind of terrain", but I would still only be interested in how to do it on a machine with 1 MB of RAM and a 7 Mhz processor, because this is the machine i currently developing games for. If that seems like a vague or meaningless question to you, that's alright, but I'm still curious if someone has any knowledge about this.

Comment: You may want to rephrase the question. See this answer about how to do that: http://meta.gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/628/7191

Comment: @Byte56: I agree that his original question could have used more details, but well, the title _does_ say "Settlers-**like**"...

Comment: @voithos Yes, it says that now that it's been edited.

Comment: @Byte56: Ah, I missed that. Oops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check [Widelands](http://wl.widelands.org/), it's an open source remake of Settlers and they have a [wiki page](http://wl.widelands.org/docs/lua/geometry/) where they explain how they made the terrain.

Comment: Here the correct link for the wikiPage with all images: 
http://wl.widelands.org/docs/lua/geometry/